# Customer Group display on "Print Shipping List" page

Tags: opencart, admin, orders

I am on Opencart 3.0.3.6.
Under the `Admin > Sales > Orders` I have an option to print invoice or shipping list.

> [Opencart order page print options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwY1T.png)

I want to show "`Customer Group`" of the shipping list page.

> [Customer Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drWuK.png)

I believe that the customer group is already pulled from the database in the

```
 Admin > Controller > Sale > order.php
```

and the twig file is

```
Admin > View > Template > Sale > order_shipping.twig.
```

I tried

```
{{ order.customer_group_id }} {{ customer_group_id }} ....
```

many combinations from the controller file but it is not showing.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

### Note: It is highly recommended to use vqmod/ocmod and avoid changing core files directly.

You need to change two files:

1. The controller: `admin/controller/sale/order.php`

   Here, the method **`shipping`** should be amended. So find `public function shipping()` and apply changes inside the function block like so:

   - Before

     ```
     $data['orders'][] = array(
     ```

     add:

     ```
     $this->load->model('customer/customer_group');

     $customer_group_info = $this->model_customer_customer_group->getCustomerGroup($order_info['customer_group_id']);

     if ($customer_group_info) {
         $order_info['customer_group'] = $customer_group_info['name'];
     } else {
         $order_info['customer_group'] = '';
     }
     ```
   - After

     ```
     $data['orders'][] = array(
     ```

     add:

     ```
     'customer_group'   => $order_info['customer_group'],
     ```
2. The template file: `admin/view/template/sale/order_shipping.twig`

   Just add `{{ order.customer_group }}` anywhere in the orders loop. For example after

   ```
   <h1>{{ text_picklist }} #{{ order.order_id }}</h1>
   ```

   add this line:

   ```
   <h2>{{ text_customer_group }}: {{ order.customer_group }}</h2>
   ```